# Getting strange touch coordinates

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm trying to detect pinch using multitouch in `onTouchEvent` of the activity. But the coordinates I'm getting are behaving erratically sometimes. For example I'm getting the following coordinates one after another and as you can see X value jumps suddenly:

```
06-08 20:48:38.625: DEBUG/(1989): X0:300.6635,Y0:655.4612
06-08 20:48:38.635: DEBUG/(1989): X1:181.23222,Y1:224.74033
06-08 20:48:38.835: DEBUG/(1989): X0:293.20694,Y0:653.9503
06-08 20:48:38.845: DEBUG/(1989): X1:185.0237,Y1:228.76929
06-08 20:48:38.845: DEBUG/(1989): X0:185.0237,Y0:653.8244 (Jumps to the X value of the other pointer)
06-08 20:48:38.845: DEBUG/(1989): X1:185.0237,Y1:228.76929
```

This is coming from Nexus One while doing a pinch gesture.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus One has a [defective multi touch sensor/software](http://www.neowin.net/news/nexus-one-has-a-major-multitouch-problem).  It seems that whenever your two fingers cross on an axis, the coordinates can get messed up.  [This app](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.metalev.multitouch.visualizer2) will help demonstrate the problem on your phone.

The good news is that this is a problem exclusive to the N1 so you can still make the application as you want, just note in the description that the N1 may have problems.

Comment: I read about that defect too but since builtin web browser zoom with pinch properly i thought that something else is wrong but the app you sent is doing the same thing so i assume that the problem is more apparent in what i am doing since i'm detecting and using horizontal & vertical pinch independently and that bug zeroes the horizontal pinch.